# about exporting function methods from .net dll (C#)

Tags: c#, dll, dllexport, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

**math.dll**

```
namespace math
{
    public class MyClass {
        public static int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x+y;
        }
    }
```

And in my exe project I want to use Add() function so,

**Example 1 - This is working**

```
    public void Example_1()
    {
                SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load("math");
                Type type = SampleAssembly.GetType("math.MyClass");
                MethodInfo methodInfo  = type.GetMethod("Add");
                if(methodInfo != null)
                {
                    object result = null;
                    ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
                    object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
                    object[] parametersArray = new object[] { 3, 5 };
                    result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
                    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
                } 
  }
```

**Example 2 - This is not working**

```
public delegate int Add(int x,int y);                
public void Example_2()
                {
                    SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load("math");
                    Type type = SampleAssembly.GetType("math.MyClass");
                    MethodInfo methodInfo  = type.GetMethod("Add");
                    if(methodInfo != null)
                    {

                    Add add = (Add)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer
                      (methodInfo.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer(),typeof(Add));
                      MessageBox.Show(add(3,2).ToString());
                    } 
              }
```

**Example 3 - This is not working**

```
public void Example_3() {

        IntPtr hdl = LoadLibrary("math.dll");
        IntPtr addr = GetProcAddress(hdl,"MyClass");
        IntPtr myfunction = GetProcAddress(addr,"Add");
        Add add= (Add)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(hdl,typeof(Add));
        MessageBox.Show(add(2,3).ToString());
}
```

**Can you tell me where is the mistakes of not working examples(2,3)?
Thanks.**

Comment: Are you trying to understand the mechanics of assemblies and methods?  Or are you simply trying to use a method in an external assembly?  If the latter, simply add an assembly reference to your project and instantiate the class directly.  You don't need to code any of these.

Comment: Yes I know that is the easiest way to add reference. as you say, I want to understand assemblies and exporting methods.thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In example 2 and 3 you are using the [`Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx) which is a function used when working with unmanaged code in order to convert an unmanaged function pointer to a managed delegate. The `math` assembly contains managed .NET code so you should use Reflection as in Example 1. So don't use this function unless you are trying to reuse functionality in an unmanaged C, C++, ... library.

You really should make the distinction between unmanaged (C, C++, ...) and managed code (.NET).

Comment: Ahh Darin again you, thanks. So I understand that I can't create same function with unmanaged code,can I?

Comment: @ocanal, your math.dll is a .NET assembly => managed code. Not unmanaged C/C++ code. If you want to create unmanaged code and use Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer then go ahead and start writing C++, not C#.